# hashmap<String,ArrayList<T>> - how to oder it alphabetical>

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have th following method. Before returning the result I ned to have the hashmap ordered alphabetically.
how to update my code in order to save in hashmap the string values in alphabetic order? The list I have is alphabetic order, but still after adding it in hashmap the hash begins with e,d,f,g and than with a,b,c,h,i...and so on. WHY?
    public Map> getSortedData
    {
    Map> result= new Hash>();
    ArrayList contacts=null;
    String currletter=null;

```
for (T c:objects)
{
if (!c.getLabel().equals(currletter))
{
contats = new ArrayList<T>();
currletter=c.getLabel();
results.put(currletter,contacts);

}
contacts/add(c);
}

how to update my code in order to save in hashmap the string values in alphabetic order? The list I have is alphabetic order, but still after adding it in hashmap the hash begins with e,d,f,g and than with a,b,c,h,i...and so on. WHY?
    //??? HERE I WOULD LIKE FIRSTLY TO SORT TH HASHMAP ALFABETICALLY AFTER THE STRING VALUE
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Simply you can not. You have to use another structure to save your data

Comment: The HashMap can't be sorted. It is part of how it works.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: ok then how to update my code in order to save in hashmap the string values inalphabetic order? The list I have is alphabetic odered, but still after adding it in hashmap the hash begins with e,d,f,g and than with a,b,c,h,i...and so on. WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for sorted result

Comment: @user1222905 It's very simple, just use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: @user1222905: Use the word TreeMap in the place of HashMap for natural sorting

Comment: can you please rewrite my code including also the alphabetic order?